# JSView passing context to deferred object

Tags: jquery, deferred, jsrender

I tried to passing the data context to a deferred object to modify the data after execute a function:

```
function confirmBox(obj){
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  //cut the function
  //if true, it will returned the obj, by false it will be defer.reject()
  defer.resolve(obj);
  return defer.promise();
}

$.link.testTemplate("#main", app)
  .on("click", ".test-item", function(e){
    confirmBox($.view(this)).then(function (answer) {
      console.log(answer.getIndex())
    });
    //console.log($.view(this).getIndex()) => working fine
  })
```

It returned an undefined value.

Where are my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`view.getIndex()` will return undefined if the context (view) is not an 'item' view, or within an item view.

http://www.jsviews.com/#getindex
http://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@index

So if your 'test-item' element is not within a `{^{for someArray}}` index will be undefined.

Your example works fine for me when 'test-item' is in an item view...

Otherwise, can you post a complete example to jsfiddle...